# Why set pop return first element while list pop return last element in python

Tags: python, stack

It's a little bit confusing. Is it actually comes from stack `pop/push` terminology?

> L.pop([index]) -> item -- remove and return item at index (default last).
>   Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.

```
>>> [1,2].pop()
2
```

> Remove and return an arbitrary set element. Raises KeyError if the set
>   is empty.

```
>>> {1,2}.pop()
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set.pop` does *not* return the first element. As it clearly says in the help that you quoted, it returns an *arbitrary* element.

And the reason for this is simple: sets are inherently unordered. There is no meaningful "first" or "last" element.<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1. Since sets are stored as hash tables, it makes sense for both performance reasons and simplicity reasons that `set.pop` will remove the first element in the hash table, which will *often* be the same as the first element iterated by the set, but that's not guaranteed. And, in fact, exactly when it's true is different in CPython 3.6 - 3.7 than in 3.3 - 3.5.</sub>

Comment: @MohanBabu Actually, forget the example I linked (which depends on your Python implementation/version and random chance); that was silly. Just consider `{2, 'a'}`. That set _has_ no smallest value, and yet `pop` works just fine.

Comment: agree @abarnert