# Use pop method on set to drop items always drops the same items

Tags: python, set

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
y = set(x)

print(y)

y.pop()
y.pop()

print(y)
```

This my my sample code. In the documentation I read that sets always drop random items, but my code always returns this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{3, 4}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or why do always the first two items get dropped? If I want to drop the last element is it necessary to transform the set to a list and then back to a set?

Comment: It’s not random it’s unpredictable if you don’t know how set’s internal storage is structured.

Comment: duplicate here see more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963946/why-set-pop-return-first-element-while-list-pop-return-last-element-in-python

Comment: It *looks* ordered because of how `int` values are hashed. Try setting `x` to a list of `str` values first.

Comment: The only conclusion seems to be : we can predict the popped item without doing the pop, as it's always the first item in the string representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you `pop` always from the same `set`. Sets don't have order, it is implementation detail how exactly are its items laid out in memory. Generally, one computes a hash function for each item and this function says which element comes first. So it is not "random" in the sense you will get different elements each run, it is "random" as in "arbitrary" meaning, you cannot rely on the apparent order.

And, btw. in CPython 3.7 `dict` are now [ordered](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/02/27/python-3-7-dictionaries-now-ordered/) (but not `set`).

Comment: `set` is not ordered.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misspoke, dict is ordered, not set. Please, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

When the documentation says it's "random" it means you **shouldn't expect anything** out of it except that it will drop an element. It doesn't necessarily mean that it's ***uniformly*** random. (Technically it is random, just not uniformly random which is what people think of when they think of randomness)

If you want to drop elements uniformly random then maybe you should consider using a list and calling shuffle on it then popping elements.

```
random.shuffle(lst)
while lst:
  print(lst.pop())
```

Comment: The docs say "arbitrary" which I believe is an attempt to not imply "random".

Comment: That would make sense, I took the users word when they said "In the documentation I read that sets always drop random items" and went off on that assumption.